# How to parse value from same tag using ElementTree in Python?

Tags: xml, parsing, python-3.6

I'm using python to parse a XML file but I have a problem. I'm getting the values in form of a dictionary but if there are two or more same values then they are not repeating. I'm sure there is a way to solve it but I'm new on python and parsing XML...

Here is an example of XML:

```
<Root>
<Child1>
</Child1>
<Child2>
    <Data DId = "1">
        <Group ID = "">
            <Sport Name="Cricket" Team="6" />
            <Sport Name="Football" Team="6" />
            <Sport Name="Hockey" Team="5" />
        </Group>
    </Data>
    <Data DId = "2">
        <Group ID = "">
            <Sport Name="Rugby" Team="6" />
            <Sport Name="Baseball" Team="10" />
            <Sport Name="Swimming" Team="6" />
        </Group>
    </Data>
</Child2>
</Root>
```

I want to get Sport's tag value separated by Data.
The code I have tried is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
dict1 = {}
for i in root.iter('Sport'):
    dict1[i.attrib['Name']] = [j.text for j in i]
    dict1[i.attrib['Team']] = [k.text for k in i]

print(dict1)
```

But I am not able to get Team value for each sport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils
xml = '''
<Root>
<Child1>
</Child1>
<Child2>
    <Data DId = "1">
        <Group ID = "">
            <Sport Name="Cricket" Team="6" />
            <Sport Name="Football" Team="6" />
            <Sport Name="Hockey" Team="5" />
        </Group>
    </Data>
    <Data DId = "2">
        <Group ID = "">
            <Sport Name="Rugby" Team="6" />
            <Sport Name="Baseball" Team="10" />
            <Sport Name="Swimming" Team="6" />
        </Group>
    </Data>
</Child2>
</Root>
'''
# xml = utils.getFileContent('test.xml')
dict1 = {}
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
datas = doc.selects('Data')
for i in datas:
    dic = {}
    for j in i.selects('Sport'):
        dic[j['Name']] = j['Team']
    dict1[i['DId']] = dic
print(dict1)
```

Result:

```
{'1': {'Cricket': '6', 'Football': '6', 'Hockey': '5'}, '2': {'Rugby': '6', 'Baseball': '10', 'Swimming': '6'}}
```

Comment: Thanks, @the_train is there a way to get these values separated by "Did" value like I want to get the count of tag present inside each "Group" tag?

Comment: @ArenMayank I changed the answer. Do you think it's what you want?

Comment: Perfect, Thanks for the suggestion @the_train.